# Dynamically get the id of the element inside the class binding in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, class, binding, vuejs3, bind

I have a vue file with about 200 of these

```
<p id="2">blabla</p>
...
```

I can easily do find and replace from `id="` to `:class="{'activeClass': currentId == idClicked}" id="`
and get this

```
<p :class="{'activeClass': currentId == idClicked}" id="2">blabla</p>
...
```

I get get the `idClicked` from the vue router, by checking the url during page load, but there is no way for me to know the `currentId` or pass it somehow in the class binding, because the HTML is static.

How can I dynamically get the element's id inside the class binding ?

Thank you

PS - I dont want to remove classes from all the elements and then add one class to one element, because that involves a big for loop and I want to avoid that.

PS
regex issue
[image]

Comment: since the html content is static just do `<p :class="{'activeClass': idClicked==2}" id="2">blabla</p>` , `<p :class="{'activeClass': idClicked==3}" id="3">blabla</p>` and so on

Comment: True, but I cannot do that by hand 200 times. Unless you have something to suggest , so I can do this automatically during find and replace. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since the HTML content is static and you've a lot of content with a common pattern, and you try to replace `<p id="index"` with `<p :class="{'activeClass': idClicked == index }" id="index"`, so you need to do this in VSCode by pressing Ctrl+H:

```
<p id="(.*)"
```

by

```
<p :class="{'activeClass': idClicked == $1 }" id="$1"
```

[image]

Comment: That is a brilliant idea. I have a small issue, if I do `id="(.*)"` as the first part, it selects the whole text inside the `<p>` if there is another `"` inside that `<p>`. How can I ake it stop to the first `"` ? Also I think the second part should be `<p :class="{'activeClass': idClicked == '$1' }" id="$1"` . Thank you

Comment: I didn't understand your issue, please clarify more

Comment: I uploaded an image in my original question above. First line works fine, chooses only the id part. Second line does not, because it selects the whole line, because there are extra " in there, in the word "Athena". Thanks again

Comment: what about `<p id="(.*)">` and `<p :class="{'activeClass': idClicked == $1 }" id="$1">`?